# Is there a way to rename an Angular variable in the view?

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope

In my Angular project, I am using a particular value that in my controller is called something like:

`$scope.feature1.items.thisItem`

There's a particular `<div>` in my view that uses `thisItem` many times and it's quite messy to be referring to it as `{{feature1.items.thisItem}}` for example:

```
<div id="{{feature1.items.thisItem}}header>
     <h1> You've reached the section about {{feature1.items.thisItem}} </h1>
</div>
```

Is there any way to rename this variable in the view? I would like to simply call it `one`. I've tried `{{feature1.items.thisItem as one}}` but that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! ng-init was designed for this very purpose - aliasing another variable:

```
<div ng-init="thisItem = feature1.items.thisItem">
     <h1> You've reached the section about {{thisItem}} </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly ng-init seems to have been removed in Angular 2+

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against using ng-init, it's not designed for this purpose.  From [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

You'll want to create a custom controller for this purpose.  Something like the following:

```
module.controller('RenameController', function($scope) {

  $scope.one = null;

  $scope.$watch('feature1.items.thisItem', function(value) {
    $scope.one = value;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) on the top of your DOM element

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="myVar=feature1.items.thisItem">
        {{myVar}}
    </div>
</div>
```